# What is in/out traction frequency in a stepper motor?

Tags: stepper-motor

I'm referring to this [spec sheet for a stepper motor](https://components101.com/sites/default/files/component_datasheet/28byj48-step-motor-datasheet.pdf).

**EDIT** Just to be clear, this is not an "I want advice on what motor to use" type of question. I just want to know what "in-traction frequency" and "out-traction frequency" on the linked spec sheet mean.

Comment: What is the nature of your application?  What sort of load do you need to drive, at what rotation rate, with what precision.  Is backlash a concern?  That's a wimpy stepper with a gearbox on it, and a very high resistance coil with a huge inductance that will limit you to very slow step rates.  There are places it might work but for a lot of projects people build that need stepper motors, this would not be workable.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'm just rotating a very light sample in a test tube and taking photos from different angles. The motor is sufficient (and I already got a batch of photos today). But the academic curiosity is still there. I found that if I try to step at a rate of 10 kHz the motor doesn't respond. 1 kHz seems to work just fine though

Comment: That's not necessarily the motor; what you may really be seeing is the inductance of that coil with enough turns to have 50 ohms of resistance.  Likely you'd need an absurdly high voltage chopping drive to get the current to rise up to something producing any reasonable torque in such a short step time.  You'd have much better results with a 200 step/revolution stepper run direct drive without the gearbox, both because you'd need lower step rates and because you'd probably get a lower inductance coil *and* a chopper drive.  Look at 3d printer motor/drive/controllers for something cheap.

Comment: Provide info on your drive circuit.  I suspect 10,000 steps per second is way too fast.  Getting beyond 2,000 steps per second is usually a challenge.  If not because of loss of torque, then instability that develops.

Comment: @whitegreg56 I'm driving this with a Rasberry pi and Python, so it's not a clean 10 kHz. It's just me turning on the right pins for each step and then pausing for T = 1/f in between. I understand physically why going to fast won't work (inductance might flatten the pulse, and the motor might have too much intertia to get between steps in time). I just want to know how to read the spec sheet so that I know what the max frequency is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Idle In-traction Frequency" propably is maximum frequency at wich motor will start and "Idle Out-traction Frequency" propably is maximum speed of motor. "Idle" means without load. In your example start is guaranted below 600 steps/second and maximum speed is not less then 1000 steps/second.
Chinese datasheets ;-)

Comment: Ah thanks! Makes sense that the motor might not start above a certain frequency as it will have too much inertia to get going.